# Bezier Curve Implementation for nth order in Excel

Tags: excel, bezier

I am trying to implement nth order bezier curve in excel. I successfully completed implementing Quadratic and Cubic Bezier Curves.

But I am unable to figure out how to calculate binomial coefficient's needed to implement bezier curve for n points in excel.

I have referred to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve from wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel formula `=COMBIN(n,i)` to calculate the binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You should use de Casteljau algorithm. Directly computing the C(n,i) binomial coefficients is not only expensive, it will also introduce numeric instabilities.